# Cascade saving a child entity is failing with JPA (Spring data + Hibernate)?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a very simple use case where I have 2 entities : Client and Email (where a Client has OneToMany Emails).

When I try to save an email alone, it works with no error, and I can see it in database afterwards :

```
  @Test
  public void insertEmail() {

    Client fetchedClient = clientRepository.findClientsFullByPdlClient("25492040401007");

    Email email = new Email();
    email.setClient(fetchedClient);
    email.setEmail("toto@gmail.com");

    emailRepository.save(email);
  }
```

But when I try my main use case, which is saving a new client with its emails using cascade, I get an error :

The test case :

```
  @Test
  public void testCreateClient() {

    Client client = new Client();
    client.setPdlClient(PDL_CLIENT_TO_CREATE);    

    Email email1 = new Email();
    email1.setEmail("toto@gmail.com");
    email1.setOrdre((short) 1);
    client.addEmail(email1);

    Email email2 = new Email();
    email2.setEmail("toto@sfr.com");
    email2.setOrdre((short) 2);
    client.addEmail(email2);

    clientRepository.save(client);

  }
```

The error :

```
WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Column 'EMAIL' cannot be null
```

Relevant parts from Client (generated by Dali + EclipseLink tools) :

```
//bi-directional many-to-one association to Email
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="client")
private List<Email> emails = new ArrayList<Email>();

public Email addEmail(Email email) {
    getEmails().add(email);
    email.setClient(this);

    return email;
}
```

Email.java (no getters/setters) :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMAIL")
public class Email {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID_EMAIL")
    private Integer idEmail;

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Client
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_CLIENT")
    private Client client;
}
```

Now if I try my cascade save right after my successful single email insertion shown above, I get a different error, showing my "email" property is set and readable !

```
ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Duplicate entry 'toto@gmail.com' for key 'AK_EMAIL'
```

So I'm a bit confused. What am I doing wrong ? If it was complaining about the absence of ID_CLIENT, I would understand, but this " 'EMAIL' cannot be null ", what is it about ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my bad, all the code above is actually working.

I had a typo :

```
Email email2 = new Email();
email.setEmail("toto@sfr.com");
email.setOrdre((short) 2);
client.addEmail(email2);
```

instead of :

```
Email email2 = new Email();
email2.setEmail("toto@sfr.com");
email2.setOrdre((short) 2);
client.addEmail(email2);
```

I could delete this question, but maybe it can be a useful working example for other people.